# Install setup without asking admin permission in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-deployment

I have created a windows application using C# NET VS2010.

In our system there are multiple users, one of user don't have write permission. When we tried to install application for the same user it gave access denied admin permission error.

Is it possible to create deployment package that can install directly in any user/system without asking admin permission?

Comment: It depends on what your application needs to do. For example, if it needs to write to the registry outside of the user's hive then you will need admin access. If everything your app does sits within the user's permissions then look in to using ClickOnce. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.100).aspx If your client machines are locked down further with group policy, you still may be out of luck.

Comment: You say the user "doesn't have write permission". But to where? He must surely have writer permission somewhere (e.g. his own profile). Do you mean he doesn't have write permission to Program Filesor something?

Comment: Thanks Mike, 
Actually scenario is as below,

Comment: We have system which don't have permission to install new application. When we try to install it ask 'access deneid. contact to vendor/admin'. We want to install application forcefully without asking above error. Can we do this in winform(c#) application setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can install an application for the currently logged in user only. But for that you need to make sure that the application doesn't need write access to places where only administrators can write. e.g. "**Program Files**", "**Windows**", "**registry other than user's own hive(**HKEY_CURRENT_USER**)" etc.

A user has complete access to his/her own profile folder and can write to it. You can install the application to user's Application Data folder (%userprofile%\AppData).
You can use this folder for installation. Install inside the "**Local(%userprofile%\AppData)**" folder